# Why does scipy's genfromtxt read NaN values as -1?

Tags: python, scipy

```
import scipy as sp
data = sp.genfromtxt(r"C:\Users\DELL INSPIRON N3542\Downloads/1400OS_Code/1400OS_01_Codes/data/web_traffic.tsv" , "\t") 
print(data[:24])

[[   1 2272]
 [   2   -1]
 [   3 1386]
 [   4 1365]
 [   5 1488]
 [   6 1337]
 ...
  and the original Data set looks like that

  1  2272
  2  nan
  3  1386
  4  1365
  5  1488
  6  1337
  ...
```

and instead of this -1 i should get a NaN , in the original Data set there's a NaN.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what's in that `.tsv` file (as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52973343/edit), just text, no images/links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `"\t"` as a datatype, not the delimiter.

Try instead:

```
import scipy as sp
data = sp.genfromtxt(r"C:\Users\DELL INSPIRON N3542\Downloads/1400OS_Code/1400OS_01_Codes/data/web_traffic.tsv", delimiter="\t")
```

I think you get the `-1` instead of `nan`, because by design, integers do not support nan, only floats do.

I am not sure why passing `"\t"` as a data type is understood as int64 and does not raise an error.